# Grouping then max on MSSQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, grouping

I have two tables as follows.

**Table 1:**

| ID | ArtNumber | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Article1 | 07.05.2022 | 100.00 |
| 2 | Article2 | 07.05.2022 | 100.00 |
| 3 | Article1 | 10.05.2022 | 100.00 |
| 4 | Article2 | 10.05.2022 | 100.00 |

**Table 2**

| ID | ArtNumber | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Article1 | 80.00 |
| 2 | Article2 | 120.00 |

I want for Table 1 the newest (Date) price for each ArtNumber. But also want to then check if the price is more than in Table 2. (Table1.Price<Table2.Price)

Expected result:

| ArtNumber | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Article2 | 120.00 |

I have tried a lot of `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, `MAX()` and `DISTINCT` combinations without success.

Comment: *"I have tried a lot of `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, `MAX()` and `DISTINCT` combinations without success."* and what were those attempts? You forgot to include them.

Comment: Why does Article2 have an `ID` of `1` in your expected results? Is `ID` actually a row number within the data set?

Comment: Seems your logic is backwards. 120 (from Table2 - nice names btw) is > 100 (from table1). You wrote "(Table1.Price>Table2.Price)"

Comment: I have also removed the column ID in the expected result (as it's not relevant). I will add an example of the attempts I have tried later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple greatest-n-per-group query:

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by artnumber order by date desc) as rn
    from table1
)
select *
from cte
join table2 on cte.artnumber = table2.artnumber
where rn = 1 and cte.price < table2.price
```